# handling special char in xml before passing to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I need to pass XML to SQL server for data processing. As XML is returned from API so there is possibility that it could contain restricted char.

Now how to I replace these char before passing XML object to SQL .

Code I am using to get XML from API is :

```
string apiurl = "http://api.abc.com/xml/2011-03-01/products?id=827&q=all&programs=8";
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString(apiurl));

                using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
                    {
                        xml.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                    }

                }
```

Before passing XML object to SQL store procedure I want to replace restricted char like

```
& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;
```

How do I do this in xml.

Comment: Just curious why do you need to do this? If you're storing XML in database, it should be stored as is.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ew0dw8s(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick.